# turning a simple c++ code into a class (runge kutta method)

Tags: c++, class

I have been extending the simple Runge Kutta example (example 2, 1D ODE) from [ODEINT](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html) .
The code itself works without trouble.

But then I tried to put everything into a class called runge_kutta and now the recursive inegration is not working anymore, the orginal line is

```
    integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type() ) ,
                    rhs , x , 1.0 , 10.0 , 0.1 , write_cout );
```

I thought that just adding "runge_kutta::"

```
        return integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type() ) , runge_kutta::rhs, x , 1.0 , 10.0 , timestep , runge_kutta::write_cout );
```

would fix the issue , but

the error message is

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'integrate_adaptive(boost::numeric::odeint::result_of::make_controlled<boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta_dopri5<double> >::type, <unresolved overloaded function type>, double&, double, double, double&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

The complete class is defined as follows:

rk.h

```
#ifndef RK_H_
#define RK_H_


#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <odeint.hpp>



using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

class runge_kutta{
public:
    runge_kutta(double beta1, double gamma1);
    void setparameter(double dist1,double grad);
    double solve(double x,double t);
    int main();
    void write_cout( const double &x , const double t );

private:
    void rhs( const double x , double &dxdt , const double t );
    double smoothen(double x);
    double beta, gamma;
    double distance, gradient;
    typedef runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;

};



#endif /* RK_H_ */
```

rk.cpp:

```
#include "rk.h"
double beta, gamma;
double dist, gradient;

void runge_kutta::rhs( const double x , double &dxdt , const double t )
    {
        dxdt = smoothen(x)*dist*abs(gradient);
    }

    void runge_kutta::write_cout( const double &x , const double t )
    {
        std::cout << t << '\t' << x << std::endl;
    }

    // state_type = double
    runge_kutta::runge_kutta(double beta1, double gamma1){
        beta = beta1;
        gamma = gamma1;
    }
    void runge_kutta::setparameter(double dist1,double grad){
        dist = dist1;
        gradient = grad;

    }
    double runge_kutta::solve(double x,double t){
        beta = 0.4;
        gamma = 0.8;
        typedef  runge_kutta_dopri5< double > stepper_type;
        return integrate_adaptive( make_controlled( 1E-12 , 1E-12 , stepper_type() ) , runge_kutta::rhs, x , 1.0 , 10.0 , timestep , runge_kutta::write_cout );
    }

    double runge_kutta::smoothen(double phix){
        if (abs(phix)<= beta)
            return 1;
        else if (abs(phix)> gamma)
            return 0;
        else
            return ((abs(phix)-gamma)*(abs(phix)-gamma)*(2*abs(phix)+gamma-3*beta)/((gamma-beta)*(gamma-beta)*(gamma-beta)));
    }
```

Comment: Guess the `integrate_adaptive` doesn't take member functions as parameters, unless they are `static`.

Comment: to call a class function, you need a class instance. so member functions cant bind to regular function pointers. you can make them static, as a quick fix

Comment: And you need to use the right syntax for the address of a member function.

Comment: if `integrate_adaptive` is a template that accepts functors, then you can `std::bind` the member functions to `this`

Comment: the problem with static is that I need to change the parameters dist,grad in used the function rhs according to x (but not related with x directly by formula). those variables are the reason why I tried to put everything into a class...

Answer (score 0):

You've replaced functions like `write_cout` with member functions, but they are not the same thing. You can't just use free functions and member functions interchangeably.

Also, to take the address of a member function you must use `&runge_kutta::write_cout` not just `runge_kutta::write_cout` (but that probably won't fix the error, for the reason above).